# Graph API count friends

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I know that facebook remove many options from open graph, but is there some options to get only friends number? I don't need to have nothing more than all friends count for user - not only number of friends who also use my app.

Is there such option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#total_friend_count)

**For people who have logged into my app with Facebook, how can my app get their total friend count?**

As of Tuesday 22nd July 2014, we now return a `total_count` field within a `summary property` in the response to `/v2.0/me/friends`. This means all upgraded apps now have access to a person's total friend count in all calls to the friends edge.

Comment: maybe You also know how make it work with koala gem? u.facebook.get_connection("me", "friends/#{summary}",api_version:"v2.0") this return error :)